# If $ A\in M_3(\mathbb{C}) $ and $\det(A+A^t)=8 $ and $\det(A+2A^t)=27$ prove $ \det(A)=1 $ and $ \det( xA+yA^t) = (x+y)^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, transpose

Let A be an 3 x 3 matrix that contains complex numbers, and $A^t$ its transpose. Considering that

$\det(A+A^t)=8  $ $  $  and $  $    $\det(A+2A^t)=27$ $  $ prove that $  $ $ \det(A)=1 $

and that $  $ $ \det( xA+yA^t) = (x+y)^3 $  $  $ for all $  $ $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$.

I need a hint to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the statement is complete? For a $3\times 3$ matrix, the two conditions don't seem to be enough to uniquely determine $\det(A)$.

Comment: It seems to be complete. For $A$ uppertriangular the claim follows easily by a direct computation. I am looking for an argument now that we may reduce it to this case.

Comment: I posted the whole statement which I took from a Mathematics Gazette. I have to admit that when I tried to solve it, I wondered too whether the statement is complete or not. ( I apologize for taking so much time to reply, a power outage occured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x)=\det((\frac 12 - x)A+(\frac 12 +x) A^t)$. This is a polynomial of variable $x$ and the degree of $g$ is at most three. The given conditions rewrite as $g(0)=1$ and $g(\frac 16)=1$. Also note that 
$$\left((\frac 12 - x)A+(\frac 12 +x) A^t\right)^t = (\frac 12 + x)A+(\frac 12 - x) A^t.$$
Applying $\det$ and using $\det X = \det X^t$ we get that $g(x)=g(-x)$ for all $x$.

So, $g$ is an even polynomial of degree at most three satisfying $g(0)=g(\frac 16)=1$. These conditions already imply that $g(x)=1$ for all $x$. I'll leave it to you as an exercise. Then it follows immediately that $\det(A)=g(-\frac 12)=1$. It is also quite easy to prove that $\det(xA+yA^t)=(x+y)^3$, just consider $g(\frac{y-x}{2(x+y)})$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! I have a question, I'm having a difficulty in trying to prove that g(x)=g(−x) and g(0)=g(1/6)=1 imply g(x)=1.  They imply that g(-1/6)=g(1/6)=g(0)=1 so the ecuation g(x)=1 has at least 3 solutions. Knowing that  g is an even polynomial of degree at most three, isn't it necessary that I find a 4th solution to g(x)=1 in order to prove that g(x)=1 for all x?

Comment: Try to write $g(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and use $g(x)=g(-x)$ to conclude that $a=c=0$.

Comment: Indeed, that was what I was missing, I have just finished it! Thank you very much, your solution is simply fantastic.